# Heroku says "Internal Server Error". What is wrong in the code

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

Heroku is showing

```
"Internal server error"
```

when i hit the "../save" route.

I tried running the code on localhost to check for error and i got the following result.

Here is my code -

**index.js**

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/public',express.static('public'));
app.set("view engine","ejs");

var port=process.env.PORT || 3000;

items = {}
obj1 = {
    name : "Gaurav Kumar Sharma",
    sentFrom : "Server",
    msg : "Index Page",
    time : new Date().toLocaleTimeString()
}

obj2 = {
    name : "Gaurav Sharma",
    sentFrom : "Server",
    msg : "Error 404",
    time : new Date().toLocaleTimeString()
}
var orgName = ""
var address = ""

//Items will be added here
app.get("/save",function(req,res){
    res.render("canvas",{orgName : orgName,address:address,items:items})
})

app.post("/savetodatabase",function(req,res){
    //console.log(req.body);
    obj1.msg = req.body.imgURL;
    res.redirect("/");
})

app.get("*",function(req,res){
    res.send("PAGE RENDERED!!, Go Back and save it.");
})

app.listen(port,function(){
    console.log("Server Started at port " + port);
})
```

**Canvas.ejs**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="640" height="840" style="border:1px solid black;"></canvas>
  <form id="getForm" action="/savetodatabase" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="imgURL" id="imgURL">
    <button id="submit">Confirm</button>
  </form>
  <script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
   ....
   ....
  start = 170
  i=1
  '<%items.forEach(function(item){%>'    
    ctx.fillText(i+".",40,start)
    ctx.fillText('<%=item.name%>',110,start)
    ctx.fillText('<%=item.rate%>',370,start)
    ctx.fillText('<%=item.quantity%>',440,start)
    ctx.fillText('<%=item.amount%>',530,start) 
    i = i + 1 
    start = start + 30
  '<%})%>'
  .....
  .....
  var img = canvas.toDataURL();
  $("#imgURL").val(img);     
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Error when i hit the route "../save" is -**

```
TypeError: /home/gaurav/Downloads/New Project/saveCanvas(azure)/views/canvas.ejs:28
    26|   start = 170
    27|   i=1
 >> 28|   '<%items.forEach(function(item){%>'    
    29|     ctx.fillText(i+".",40,start)
    30|     ctx.fillText('<%=item.name%>',110,start)
    31|     ctx.fillText('<%=item.rate%>',370,start)

items.forEach is not a function
    at eval (eval at compile (/home/gaurav/Downloads/New Project/saveCanvas(azure)/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:633:12), <anonymous>:17:13)
    at returnedFn (/home/gaurav/Downloads/New Project/saveCanvas(azure)/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:668:17)
    at tryHandleCache (/home/gaurav/Downloads/New Project/saveCanvas(azure)/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:254:36)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/home/gaurav/Downloads/New Project/saveCanvas(azure)/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:485:10)
    at View.render (/home/gaurav/Downloads/New Project/saveCanvas(azure)/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (/home/gaurav/Downloads/New Project/saveCanvas(azure)/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (/home/gaurav/Downloads/New Project/saveCanvas(azure)/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (/home/gaurav/Downloads/New Project/saveCanvas(azure)/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1012:7)
    at /home/gaurav/Downloads/New Project/saveCanvas(azure)/app.js:65:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/gaurav/Downloads/New Project/saveCanvas(azure)/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```

**Error showing in console is-**

[image]

I should expect a rendered canvas with data that i sent in the route-

```
res.render("canvas",{orgName : orgName,address:address,items:items})
```

Help me to fix the error.

Comment: `items` is an Object, not an Array. There's no `forEach` function for Objects.

Comment: Learn to post only relevant code and you will have your questions answered easier. Nobody wants to read 50 lines of code, count the lines to know what's the line pointed on error.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisG I got the mistake.